# Is there any search tools like "everything" on MacOS?

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

Now I want to search a file exists or not on my mac, when I am using Windows, I can using the everything tool that searching any files less than 50ms on the disk, I was wonder if there is any tool like this in macOS to let me searching any files quickly, I am using this find command, it is too slow. I am using the spotlight but I still not sure it shows all the files on disk.

Comment: What kind of research have you done on this (including looking for similar questions on Ask Different)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spotlight does not index all files, but is real time and fast.

If you want a graphical tool, use [Find Any File](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/find-any-file-faf/id402569179?mt=12) there are many alternatives, but this one is superb.

Command line tools:

- `mdfind` can do amazing complex tasks if the path is indexed
- `locate` exceptionally fast, rebuilds the database index in the background periodically, only cares about filesystem names and paths.

Comment: Was about to mention `locate` command! Also with the versatility of shell you can pipe output to `grep` for more precise filtering of output.

Comment: @melonee Even `locate` itself understands wildcards :-)

Comment: How do we know if a path is already indexed?

Comment: I run a search for a specific term that has few or no hits and make a file and seee if it shows up or search for a file I know exists @Alper . Let me know here if you ask that as a proper question and I’ll take a stab at answering

Comment: Find Any File isn't indexed, which means it won't do a search in 50ms like the OP requested.  Only indexed searches can do that.

Comment: Spotlight is *not* "fast (from my software engineer perspective), and 1-3 seconds of latency still exists with latest/greatest hardware and macOS version.

Comment: Interesting observation @anthumchris - I have it live and real time. The `mdfind -live` tool on the command line updates with streaming results the instant a file is saved to disk. How are you measuring your latency?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a software called **EasyFind** which is very similar to **Everything**, and the best part is that it's free.

I recommend you to give it a try.

https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware

Answer (score 0):

OP was looking for a fast, indexed search on Mac OSX.  ProFind appears to fit the bill.  It's just $6.99.

I've tried all of the free alternatives listed on alternativeto.net, but they're all very slow at indexing, most won't show when a directory matches, and their interfaces are super clunky.

Using a free trial of ProFind, I was able to index 100k files on a network share in under 5 minutes (others took 20+), and do full searching in under a second.  It can match to directories that match your search criteria too!  (I don't work for them, I just did a long search / testing and wanted to share my results for the next person in my shoes)

http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/profind/index.html